# Planetside graphic problem!

Tags: planetside-2

I just bought Planetside 2, but when I join a server, the textures are really bad.  The weapons looks like something that isn't rendered, and the ground is pixellated.  As I said, it looks like the game isn't rendering.  But some of the thing looks okay from a distance.

When I select high graphics, it doesn't change anything, and I know I have to restart the game.  It's lagging very badly, but I can run battlefield perfect without any problems, so it's not my PC.

My friend can run it perfect and the game looks amazing on his PC, and it's not laggy.
His computer is only a little better then mine.

My PC specs:

- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560
- AMD Athlon II X2 250 3.00GHz
- 4 GB RAM (3.25 GB usable)

Comment: We're going to need a bit more info than, "the graphics are really bad".  Define bad.  Artifacts?  Glitching?  If it's lagging at high graphics, it sounds like your computer can't handle what you're asking of it.

Comment: Also don't use graphics, do you mean textures not popping in? Particles are showing up as tiny pixels? Are the textures really pixelated?

Comment: With the edit: Sounds more like the textures just aren't popping in (Meaning it's not swapping to it's high res version). Also Planetside 2 is in beta so this is expected to a point. Finally a framerate issue probably isn't due to the textures not popping but instead to the high number of people and events going on, it might be CPU instead. I need specs.

Comment: my pc specs:
Graphic card: NVIDEA GeForce GTX 560  
Processer: AMD Athlon II X2 250 3.00GHz  
Ram: 4,00 GB (3.25 GB usable)  
that was all i could find say if you need more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your framerate issue is likely due to a CPU bottleneck. The core speed on your CPU is very high but it's only two cores. Your framerate issues are likely worst where there are a lot of people and fighting (more so than normal) but the game is probably smooth where it is more empty. Your CPU dictates how many actions can go on at once on your screen without slow down.

The texture issues are likely either A: from drivers not being up to date or B: The game is in beta and it is to be expected. There really not much you can do while the game is in beta as the issue may suddenly be fixed when you log in one day and it's not worth troubleshooting as the game goes. Also since the game is not out yet, Nvidia likely doesn't have any drivers that are tuned for the game itself and haven't fully tested it yet.

For now you should just deal with the textures issues but the framerate can be remedied by a new CPU. However fair warning, upgrading a CPU often means a new motherboard as well since you need a new socket.